# Skip parts of source tree when building Java with gradle

Tags: java, gradle

Let’s assume I have a Java project I’d like to build with gradle, but I’d like gradle to skip certain packages/parts of the source tree.

If the source tree has a nonstandard layout, I can specify this in the following manner:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['src']
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to tell gradle to ignore everything in `src/org/example/foo/barproject/ui` but build the rest? If so, how?

Comment: `src/org/example/foo/barproject/ui` or `src/main/org/example/foo/barproject/ui`?

Comment: @chenrui the former, as indicated by the nonstandard `srcDirs`

Comment: also, I assume this is Gradle 1.10, right?

Comment: @chenrui correct ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir = ['src']
            exclude "main/*"
            exclude "hello/*"
            exclude "test/*"
        }
    }
}
```

My folder layout:

```
$ ls -R src
Library.java hello        main         test

src/hello:
Application.java     HelloController.java

src/main:
java

src/main/java:
Library.java hello

src/main/java/hello:
Application.java     HelloController.java

src/test:
java

src/test/java:
LibraryTest.java
```

Output:

```
$ ./gradlew clean build -x test
Creating properties on demand (a.k.a. dynamic properties) has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please read http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html for information on the replacement for dynamic properties.
Deprecated dynamic property: "srcDir" on "source set 'main'", value: "[src]".
:clean
:compileJava
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:jar
:assemble
:check
:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.935 secs
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks, this did it. Unfortunately, after trying it out I’ll also need to exclude other classes scattered all over the codebase—so while this does what I expect it to, I’ll have to try a different approach.